# Update Drupal Core from 6.26 to 6.36 using update.php gave no errors, but Drupal still reports that it is on version 6.26

Tags: 6, updating

I've followed all of the steps on https://www.drupal.org/upgrade/running-update-php to upgrade my Drupal Core.

I put the site into maintenance mode.
I disabled all modules except the core required modules.
I used FTP to delete all of the folders associated with the upgrade.
I copied the entire directory of contents except .htaccess and robots.txt and part of my sites directory
I navigated to subsite.site.com/update.php
I ran the update
The update indicated that it performed 0 / 0 tasks and said it completed
I navigated to the administration page
I cleared cache
I reenabled modules
I checked the current upgrade status

Result: It still read that I was on 6.26
Expected result: It reads that I'm on 6.36

Quite confused about this. I have successfully upgraded my modules using the update.php script with no problems.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check that some of the core module files have 6.36 in their respective .info files? Once core has been updated the core modules have their corresponding versions updated to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Alex.  When I navigate to subsite.site.com/admin/build/modules, it shows the core modules all as version 6.26.  But, when I FTP into my site and look at the .info files for each of the modules, they all list:

name = System
description = Handles general site configuration for administrators.
package = Core - required
version = VERSION
core = 6.x

; Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2015-06-17
version = "6.36"
project = "drupal"
datestamp = "1434567252"

Comment: This is going to be a stupid question, did you FTP into the correct directory? it seems, based on your response that you might have several (or a couple) drupal sites on your host.

Comment: Good question (the stupid ones are usually the most revealing), but yes, I am certain.

I'm looking into seeing if I need to force the php cache to be cleared, but I don't have access to myphpadmin at the moment, so I'm trying to see what can be forced outside of that....I've cleared the cache under Site config: Performance.  I've also verified that I do not have any duplicate modules in the /modules and in /sites/all/modules

Answer (score -1):

Have you manually brought your codebase up to version 6.36 by overlaying 6.24 with 6.36?

The update.php will only update the database to the latest version of Drupal installed.  So if it's still 6.24, it makes sense to me that it is applying 0 of 0.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1223018

Comment: Using FTP, I copied over the new Drupal 6.36 to my root directory of the FTP site.  All of the modules that I have on the FTP site claim to be 6.36, but when I look at the admin page of my site, they all read 6.26.

Comment: update.php updates the database tables, not the codebase; differently, updating Drupal will never work when done from FTP.